# Two table views with data and want to delete a index from one specific tableview. Do I have to delete the other array also?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, memory

Ok so I am geting memory errors from this which is annoying ,since it isn't something like a simple syntax error. Well the thing I am doing to understanding how to manipulate data

What I am trying to do is to allow it to delete from another view ,but the thing still crashes. I will share the two table views I got going on.

This is the one that has problems ,since it is in the second view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FeedCommands.commentSection.count
}

//allows us to delete the code
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if editingStyle == .delete {
        // this is called from a static variable class function
        FeedCommands.RemoveComment(atIndex: indexPath.row)
        CommentFeed.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
     }
}
```

Now this is the one that works perfectly fine

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FeedCommands.feedArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
       FeedCommands.feedArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       TabView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

If I ran the problem one it exits with a memory error, I am thinking that it might have to deal with the arrays and might be the actual cause. I searched and there doesn't really seem to be anything that covers this case when doing multiple tableviews.

Here is the class I am calling the arrays from

```
static var commentSection: Array<String> = []
class func AddToComment(newElement: String){
   FeedCommands.commentSection.append(newElement)
}
class func RemoveComment (atIndex: Int){
    FeedCommands.commentSection.remove(at: atIndex)
}

static var QuestionToComment: Array<String> = []
class func AddQuestionToComment(newElement: String){
    FeedCommands.QuestionToComment.append(newElement)
}
class func RemoveQuestionToComment (atIndex: Int){
    FeedCommands.QuestionToComment.remove(at: atIndex)
}

static var feedArray: Array<String> = []

class func AddToFeed (newElement: String){
    FeedCommands.feedArray.append(newElement)
}
class func Remove (atIndex: Int){
    FeedCommands.feedArray.remove(at: atIndex)
}
```

If it needs more details please let me know.

Edit: Due to a request

this is the comment section file

```
import UIKit

class Comments: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var ReplyTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentFeed: UITableView!
    @IBAction func SubmitReply(_ sender: UIButton) {
        CommentFeed.reloadData()
        if ReplyTextField.text == nil {
        }
        else{
        FeedCommands.AddToComment(newElement: ReplyTextField.text!)
        ReplyTextField.text = ""
        }
       // dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       // ReplyTextField.placeholder = "Comment"


    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //this is what we use to get the question to
        //appear in the comment section
        Question.text = ""
        for Section in FeedCommands.QuestionToComment{
            Question.text = "\(Section)"
            CommentFeed.reloadData()
        }

    }

    //adding the table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FeedCommands.commentSection.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = CommentFeed.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Com", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "@\(Question.text!)__ \(FeedCommands.commentSection[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

    //allows us to delete the code
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            FeedCommands.commentSection.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)  // crashes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "memory error"? Where does it crash? What is the specific error on the specific line it crashes?

Comment: OK so the memory error is the abort thing that takes me straight to the app delegate section. "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". It crashes when I execute the first code I said that has problems as state above in the prompt

Comment: Also let me mention I checked all of my main storyboard  and they are fine with no warnings. The view controller is fine also ,since it works perfectly ,but the one I stated first is the one having problems. I posted the one that works to give you something more clues as these are the best I can provide ,unless if you want the whole source code that is the equivalent to a novel.

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: The line once it enters the function I checked in debug mode I double checked it was connected . I send a video that shows what’s going on if that might help.

Comment: The first section has 4 executable lines. Knowing which one it crashes on is the only way I can help you. For example, is it crashing trying to get a count of the FeedCommands array size? Or on the line trying to remove a comment from FeedCommands?

Comment: Ops sorry forgot . Yea the function where it tries to remove it it when the problems arise.  When I start the remove comment section . I can pm a video that I think would show everything i might’ve missed . Would you prefer that or just text or screenshot based. One the allies us to delete this enters the function it jump straight into the app delegate

Comment: @RandyHill I guess you could say 2 is since that’s around the tim it enters the function with problems

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry this like a rough draft then I clean up the code later. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @LeoDabus  are you sure about that?

Comment: I must be blind as a bat then or I read to fast probably.

Comment: Nope the thing is fine. I 'll get my CS teacher to look through this on Tuesday ,since I am making this app for our robotics team to get past the no service inside the arena. I can message a video inside a discussion to give all the details ,since a picture is worth a thousand words ,so you can see everything going on.

Comment: I just realized that. Sorry I am dyslexic everyone in a while when I read too fast

Comment: @LeoDabus I think this is almost impossible to solve unless if I post it in a video where you see everything going on. I tried it, it does the same thing an crashes

Comment: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Int'"

Comment: Yes I am. I will get back to you in two seconds and test it out

Comment: Ops sorry like I said. I can be dyslexic when I read to fast sorry

Comment: Ok so removing the row and not the array crashes it.

Comment: Still crashing copied straight from my compiler.FeedCommands.commentSection.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

Comment: Doesn't crash ,but it doesn't delete.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure.

Comment: Ok I will post every file then.

Comment: I will also post the screenshot of where is takes me when it crashes

Comment: Yes I did.  https://imgur.com/a/ngzFE

Comment: They are notes. I left it in there to remind myself what I tried so I don't run into a wall the same way over and over again

Comment: editingStyle delete
commentSection removed after that it crashed. Let me report what the console says ,since that might also help out. Also I wanted to say thank you so much for helping me before we continue.

Comment: 2018-01-19 18:34:49.658676-0700 PracticeSwift2[2890:242521] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UITableView.m:2011
2018-01-19 18:34:49.666865-0700 PracticeSwift2[2890:242521] ***

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: after that is pulls up a bunch of memory locations

Comment: I think I did your instructions incorrect as it crashed again

Comment: 'tableView.beginUpdates()'
        'print(#function)'
        'if editingStyle == .delete {'
            'print("editingStyle delete")'
           ' FeedCommands.commentSection.remove(at: indexPath.row)'
            'print("commentSection removed")'
            'tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)'
           ' print("tableView deleted Rows")'
            'tableView.endUpdates()'

Comment: @LeoDabus After going into debugging mode the console printed out the last text ,but right after it hit into the memory error

Comment: @LeoDabus It doesn't crash if I note out the tableview.dendUpdates() , but doesn't delete still.

Comment: So I am practically creating a temp variable to store the value ?

Comment: Yea, I think that would be better. How do you want me to distribute it?

Comment: That is the project

Comment: @LeoDabus you got it ?

Comment: @LeoDabus I am going to delete the comment soon. Just need to confirm you got it before hand

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1s2w4ozqjxumug/PracticeSwift2%20copy.zip?dl=0 This one is working

Comment: @LeoDabus Hey that's just my prototype so I would love feed back period. I am going to rebuild it into a more better version after I get the basic functionality down in that.

Comment: I loving the input keep it up. My robotics team will love this when I apply your input to the app in the final draft.

Comment: @LeoDabus how is it going so far?

Comment: @LeoDabus Is it that bad?!?!?

Comment: I have a CS teacher helping me out every here and there and guided tutorials. I also read a good chunk of the first book.  Although it is by no means equal to the amount of skill I have with C++, it does seem enough to get into the interactive lessons that are personally help a ton with learning the code and how to get a understanding of what's going on. I also reverse engineer the code ,so there isn't a line that I don't know what goes on in the program.

Comment: @LeoDabus I will definitely try it in my free time though and implement it into my learning plan

Comment: @LeoDabus  I said that was a rough draft remember ? I didn't intend it on someone else seeing it ,but the final draft (which is the code cleaned up and naming conventions fixed)

Comment: I am looking at it already, thanks.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hey I probably never would've run into this way if it weren't for you. I am grateful for this.

Comment: This seems to not work with some of the stuff inside. I will definitely keep singletons in mind though and work on projects from scratch with those

Comment: @LeoDabus Did you find the problem now?

Comment: @LeoDabus forgot to mention that you have to enter it twice the first time then after that it works perfectly fine. (replies).

Comment: @LeoDabus I also didn't do any auto layout constraints yet so I don't know what you are talking about. I designed it specifically for the iPhone 8 and was going to auto layout it on the final draft.

Comment: @LeoDabus you see what I meant around the reply button? You have to enter in once where it clears then after that if works perfectly fine.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok. I 'll try asking my CS teacher, but I am really grateful for you input. Everything is mostly functional ,but with the delete button for some odd reason, and the reply (you just have to pass the one entry then it works perfect.)

Comment: I will try to check fix it once I get a chance and will give you a feedback on it

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok thank you so much man. I am really grateful for this. Sorry about this as this is really tricky problem for some odd reason. I think my CS teacher would scratch his head too, but he has strong programming logic to help me out. (I can explain every line of code in the program. If I can't teach it, I don't understand it).

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle I found the issue

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7cv044b1492n67/PracticeSwift2%20copy%202.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reloading the table view data before appending a new element to your table view instead of reloading it after appending the reply. Thats why you needed to press your button twice to make it appear. What you should actually do to fix your submit reply action is to insert a new row at the last index (count - 1) of your table view every time the SubmitReply button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func SubmitReply(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !ReplyTextField.text!.isEmpty{
        FeedCommands.AddToComment(newElement: ReplyTextField.text!)
        ReplyTextField.text = ""
        CommentFeed.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: FeedCommands.commentSection.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: You made me have tears of joy. Thank you so much